# How to encrypt and decrypt a particular filed in a Database

Tags: mysql, database, security, encryption, database-security

I have a simple question for you and I would like to know if there are some best practices.
I have a mysql table that has a field that points to a filesystem (a link to an image).
I would like to encrypt this item and, when it will be the time, I would decrypt it.
I give you an example to better understand:
A list al students who each has a list of homework stored in a file system. The table Homework has a foreign key to a particular Student. The Homework table has a link in which the pdf homework is stored in file system. I would stored in the db the homework's link ciphered.
When I want to get all the homeworks belonging to a student I have to encrypt the link.

How can I manage this?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: I think you mean encrypt and decrypt!?!

Comment: yes man, sorry. I mean exactly that

Comment: Well, while I'm a great fan of MySQL, other RDBMSs may be able to handle this kind of thing better.

Comment: @Strawberry thank you for your answer, but what do you mean? What kind of RDBMS could manage better this?

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: Look into concepts such as 'data-at-rest encryption'. Depending on how important this stuff is to you, you may want to look at using the Enterprise edition of MySQL, or MariaDB (or Oracle, Postgres etc.)